# Deactivate fullPage.js on certain width media query

Tags: jquery, fullpage.js

I want to deactivate the fullPage.js plugin on mobile devices. Any idea how I can do that? Perhaps with a screen width media query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `responsiveWidth` [option](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js#fullpagejs), which reverts to normal scrolling under the specified screen width (in pixels). There is also a `responsiveHeight` option.